# Using Copy Raster in ArcPy gives different result to tool dialog?

Tags: arcpy, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert 16 unsigned bit tifs to 8 unsigned bit BMPs. When I used the Export Raster in ArcGIS, it works well. But when I used arcpy

```
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(each,
                            "E:/HutDetection/17.bmp","DEFAULTS",
                            "","","","","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","","","BMP","")
```

the output images is too bright and its pixel value is not the same as the one got from ArcGIS. 
I have changed the parameters a lot of times but I cant get the result I want.

What is the problem?

result from arcpy:
[image: result from arcpy]

result from arcgis:
[image: result from arcgis]

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have any stretching on the raster in the layer properties? This often happens by default and can affect the way the raster is displayed.

Comment: As @Fezter check the Layer Properties, I have seen this happen often.

Comment: Thanks. These 2 pictures use the same color map in arcMap. But after changing stretching in arcMap, the image is still too bright.  I guess it may be because of the copy Raster tool, do you know how I should use this tool to get the correct result?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but from the documentation (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm) it seems ScalePixelValue should be turned on?